# Index Error in python, list index out of range

Tags: python, csv

I use this script to manipulate a csv and upload it to database, this have been used multiple times with no problem. Today I was running it but got this list index out of range which does not make any sense to me. The script have the following commands:

```
csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file,dialect='excel-tab')
        data=[row for row in csv_reader]
        fieldnamesreader = [I for I in data[0].keys()]
```

This last line is where it gave me the error:

```
 File "MyScript.py", line 108, in main
    fieldnamesreader = [I for I in data[0].keys()]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm using python 2.7

Comment: data is of length 0? hence data[0] throwing error

Comment: can you please put sample CSV file for reference ?

Comment: Add condition to check if file is not empty

Comment: file is empty! I just feel so dumb right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file is empty, hence data becomes an empty list.